# python how to split test files from code into separate directories

Tags: python, unit-testing

Below is a fizzbuzz program done TDD using unittest in one file, I run it in the command line using `python fizzbuzz.py -v`.

```
import unittest

class FizzBuzz():
    def fizz_buzz(self, number):
        if number % 3 == 0 and number % 5 == 0:
            return 'fizzbuzz'

        if number % 3 == 0:
            return 'fizz'

        if number % 5 == 0:
            return 'buzz'

        return str(number)

class FizzBuzzTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.fb = FizzBuzz()

    def test_one_gets_one(self):
        self.assertEqual('1', self.fb.fizz_buzz(1))

    def test_three_gets_fizz(self):
        self.assertEqual('fizz', self.fb.fizz_buzz(3))

    def test_five_gets_buzz(self):
        self.assertEqual('buzz', self.fb.fizz_buzz(5))

    def test_six_gets_fizz(self):
        self.assertEqual('fizz', self.fb.fizz_buzz(6))

    def test_fifteen_gets_fizzbuzz(self):
        self.assertEqual('fizzbuzz', self.fb.fizz_buzz(15))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I decided to split the file, as having the tests separate will read better.

The tree structure is

```
|-fizzbuzz
   |-app
     - __init__.py
     -fizzbuzz.py
   |-tests
     - __init__.py
     -test_fizzbuzz.py
```

I split the file as below (only showing part of it, one test and passing code)

```
#fizzbuzz.py
class FizzBuzz():
    def fizz_buzz(self, number):
        return str(number)
```

and

```
#test_fizzbuzz.py
import unittest
from fizzbuzz import FizzBuzz

class FizzBuzzTests(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.fb = FizzBuzz()

    def test_one_gets_one(self):
        self.assertEqual('1', self.fb.fizz_buzz(1))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

In the fizzbuzz directory, i run tests with `python tests/test_fizzbuzz.py` which should pass.

But when I comment out the `return str(number)` or remove it, I still pass.

If I change `self.assertEqual('1', self.fb.fizz_buzz(1))` to `self.assertEqual('12', self.fb.fizz_buzz(1))` it is still running the code which is not there.

I deleted all the `.pyc` files in the test directory and now I get `ImportError: No module named fizzbuzz` error

If I move the `fizzbuzz.py` file into the test folder and run `python tests/test_fizzbuzz.py` the tests pass (this is how I got the .pyc files). But this is not what i want.

Why is this? Have I split this file up wrong? Am I missing extra code or files?

If I have split it up wrongly, what would be the best way to do so?

Any help appreciated, thanks.

Comment: `fizzbuzz.py` needs to be on your `PYTHONPATH`. But your use of `__init__.py` suggests that you want to use packages, in which case `app` is needs to be in your `PYTHONPATH`, and you should import `app.fizzbuzz`

Answer (score 1):

It has to do with how python finds and executes code.

Python looks for modules/scripts/packages using `sys.path`.
When you run a python script, it appends the directory of that script to `sys.path` which would be `/etc/fizzbuzz/tests`. This will not let python find the folder that contains `fizzbuzz` because it is in the directory above and not seen by python.

The easiest answer would be to add the file path to the directory above fizzbuzz to an evironment variable called **PYTHONPATH**. If the environment variable doesn't exist you can create it and python will add any directories in it to the sys.path.

Once this is done you will need to adjust a few things.

The import statements in test_fizzbuzz will need to change

```
from fizzbuzz.app import fizzbuzz
```

and change when you create fizzbuzz to

```
fizzbuzz.FizzBuzz()
```

alternatively you could change the import to:

```
from fizzbuzz.app.fizzbuzz import FizzBuzz
```

and you wouldn't need to change anything else.

Last thing, if you want to run any and all tests in the **tests** folder then you can run

```
python -m unittest discover tests
```

from the command line within the fizzbuzz project directory and it should find and run all tests in the tests folder. This would mean you wouldn't need the

```
if name == '__main__':
```

in the python files.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks managed to solve it. Just used [python the hard way setup](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex46.html) and used nosetest to run the tests and everything worked.